# How to throttle a Flux

Tags: java, project-reactor

Using Reactor, I would like to limit the rate at which events are published from a Flux, e.g. to a maximum of 10 Hz, while discarding all elements in between. The only thing I found is `delayElements()`, but this will queue up elements if they arrive at a faster rate, right? I'd like to some somethings like `someFlux.throttle(10).subscribe()` to make the Flux return at max. 10 elements a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a `sample(Duration)`, so you could do:

```
source.sample(Duration.ofMillis(100));
```

(100 milliseconds = 1/10th of a second, so you'd get at most 1 element every 100ms, ie. 10 elements every second)

edit: for a proper `throttle`, consider also `sampleFirst(v -> Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(100))` to drop all items that follow a propagated item within 100ms

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for!